# How to count the values corresponding to each unique value in another column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table like this:

```
Car Type |  Color  |  ID
 VW      |  Blue   | 123
 VW      |  Red    | 567
 VW      |  Black  | 779
 -----------------------
 AUDI    | Silver  | 112
 AUDI    | Black   | 356
 AUDI    | White   | 224
```

how can i get something like this? where each row contains the count of colors for each car type?

```
Car Type |  Color  |  ID | Total
 VW      |  Blue   | 123 |  3
 VW      |  Red    | 567 |  3
 VW      |  Black  | 779 |  3
 -----------------------
 AUDI    | Silver  | 112 |  3
 AUDI    | Black   | 356 |  3
 AUDI    | White   | 224 |  3
```

Cheers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use for number of unique values per groups use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
df['Total'] = df.groupby('Car Type')['Color'].transform('nunique')
```

Use for count values per groups use [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html):

```
df['Total'] = df.groupby('Car Type')['Color'].transform('size')
```

Difference with changed one value:

```
df['Total_uniq'] = df.groupby('Car Type')['Color'].transform('nunique')
df['Total_size'] = df.groupby('Car Type')['Color'].transform('size')
print (df)
  Car Type   Color   ID  Total_uniq  Total_size
0       VW    Blue  123           2           3
1       VW    Blue  567           2           3 <- set value to Blue
2       VW   Black  779           2           3
3     AUDI  Silver  112           3           3
4     AUDI   Black  356           3           3
5     AUDI   White  224           3           3
```

Comment: Thank you guys, i did not know about that option, would you mind a bit of explanation on how .transform would accomplish it? whats the logic?

Comment: @edgarleninlizarragagastelum - Sure, logic is use aggregate data - e.g. here `nunique` and instead aggregation fill values of all values of group so possible created new column. Similar is used each aggregate function, e.g. `transform('sum')`. Only necessary is always specify column for test function after `groupby`, here `['Color']`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option similar to Jezrael, who beat me to it!

```
import pandas as pd 
a = {'Car type':['VW','VW','VW','AUDI','AUDI','AUDI'],'Color':['Blue','Red','Black','Silver','Black','White'],'ID':[123,567,779,112,356,224]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
df_a = df.merge(df.groupby(['Car type'],as_index=False).agg({'Color':'nunique'}),how='left',on='Car type').rename(columns={'Color_x':'Color','Color_y':'Unique_colors'})
```

Output:

```
  Car type   Color   ID  Unique_colors
0       VW    Blue  123              3
1       VW     Red  567              3
2       VW   Black  779              3
3     AUDI  Silver  112              3
4     AUDI   Black  356              3
5     AUDI   White  224              3
```